# How to handle connection drops in spring rabbit ?

Tags: spring-rabbit

How can I handle the connection dropping from my rabbit server in spring-rabbit ? Are there any specific options I need to set ? Config shown below :

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="${rabbitmq.host:rserver1}" port="${rabbitmq.port:5672}"
    username="guest" password="guest" />

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:queue name="Q1.${server.name:unknown}"  />
<rabbit:queue name="Q2.${server.name:unknown}"  />

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <rabbit:listener queues="Q2.${server.name:unknown}" ref="q1QueueConsumer" />
    <rabbit:listener queues="Q2.${server.name:unknown}" ref="q2QueueConsumer" />
</rabbit:listener-container>


<rabbit:topic-exchange name="Exchange">

  <rabbit:bindings>
    <rabbit:binding queue="Q1.${server.name:unknown}" pattern="#.Q1.#" />
     <rabbit:binding queue="Q2.${server.name:unknown}" pattern="#.Q2.#" />
  </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring rabbit can automatically handle reconnecting to the broker. Just be careful as the 1.0.0 Release doesnt play nice with the 1.8.x releases of RabbitMQ

Comment: But there is an unresolved problem with Listener Reconnect: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/AMQP-259